# Change Jenkins user password remotely

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson, jenkins-cli

We have a Jenkins job which is triggered remotely through python-jenkins api. The Jenkins host is authenticated through centralized user created through "Jenkins’ own user database". Since these credentials are used across team, I want to change password once in a month. Is there a way to do it through script?

P.S. - Python api gets username/password through a key management service.